# Data Tables - Cell manipulation

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm attempting to use jQuery DataTables to show rows of tickets with each row being a new ticket and each ticket having various cells  being:

- Client
- Status
- Priority
- Subject
- Date

Rows in the table obviously look as follows by default

```
Client      Status      Priority     Subject     Date
```

However, the eventual layout of a row would be:

```
Client                      Status      Priority

Subject                                     Date
```

I have combined each cell into the same (first) cell using the code below with the intention of then achieving the desired layout. However it doesn't appear to be the right solution.

```
    "columnDefs": [
    {

        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return data +' '+ row[1]+' '+ row[2]+' '+ row[3]+' '+ row[4]+' '+ row[5];

        },
        "targets": 0
    },

    { "visible": false, "targets": [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]}

    ],
```

Is this type of manipulation possible with jQuery DataTables?

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle so we can try to help using that?

Comment: You can use child rows as in [Row details example](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html) to display additional details. You can format child rows as you want. Does that look as what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return row[0] + "<br/>" + row[3];
            }
        },
        null,
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row){
                return row[2] + "<br/>" + row[4];
            }
        },
        {
            "visible": false
        },
        {
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
});
```

Remember to alter your `thead` though:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th colspan="2">Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/kazdg2er/). You'll need to style things as well I guess and perhaps think about the ordering, if you enable it. Column names don't match with your but the structure is the same. Hope that helps.